Summation of finite geometric series
Kathryn deposits 100 into an account at the beginning of each 4-year period for 40 years. The
account credits interest at an annual effective interest rate of i.
The accumulated amount in the account at the end of 40 years is X, which is 5 times the
accumulated amount in the account at the end of 20 years.
Calculate X.
I got the answer using future value formulae, but I'm trying to understand a different method.
If the 40-year account = 5 x 20-year account, and if $y = (1+i)^4$, then
$y^{10} + y^9 + y^8 + y^7 + y^6$ = 5.
Or, $\sum_{i=6}^{10} y^i = \frac{y^6 - y^{11}}{1-y}$ = 5.
I then get $y^{11} - y^6 - 5y + 5 = 0$.
Is this correct so far?
How can I solve this equation?
Thanks!

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

I'd use a different starting equation:
$$
100\sum_{n=1}^{10}y^n = 5\times 100\sum_{n=1}^5y^n\\
\frac{y-y^{11}}{1-y}=5\frac{y-y^6}{1-y}\\
y^{11}-5y^6+4y=0\\
x^2-5x+4=0\\
(x-1)(x-4)=0
$$
or $y=0$ (i.e. $i=-100\%$) where $x=y^5$, so $y=4^{1/5}$ (i.e. $i\approx32.0\%$). Note that $x=1\implies y=1\implies i=0\%$ is not a valid solution, since we multiplied by $1-y$.

This is helpful,, thank you. I dont need the AVs, I can use the sums. Curious to know if you have an opinion about y11−y6−5y+5=0? It is nagging me.

Opinion about why that's not the right equation, or about what the solution to the wrong equation is? As for the right equation, you'd need to say what your thinking was to get it: you've presumably divided through to get 5 on the RHS, so what was the equation before that? As for the solution, it's numeric: $y \approx 1.2864$ and there are five complex conjugate pairs. (There are also complex solutions to the equation in my answer, I just gave the real one $y=4^{1/5}$.)
